# Updating Docker, Docker Machine, Docker Compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-machine

I am trying to update my docker related tools for macOS and I am unsure of how to go about it the following is my docker versions

> Docker version 1.12.6, build 78d1802 
>   docker-machine version 0.9.0, build 15fd4c7 
>   docker-compose version 1.9.0, build 2585387

I do not use docker for mac and interact with docker via the command line. So my question is....How do I upgrade them individually or otherwise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use this link to download the new versión of docker, docker-machine and toolbox https://download.docker.com/mac/stable/Docker.dmg And continue using docker-machine